# Hammer.js elements in absolute container scroll container

Tags: javascript, css, hammer.js

I have some elements I want to drag with hammer.js that are inside an absolute positioned container. When the container is absolute position, it seems like when I drag the elements in the container, the whole container moves too.

Here is a demo,
http://codepen.io/bzamora/pen/vGAFz

I used the drag demo from https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/examples/drag.html but I added a `.container` that is absolute positioned.

If you comment out the `position:absolute` it works as expected

So my question is what am I doing wrong or how to avoid this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: I tried position:relative, and it has the same issue. I would understand the dots dragging weird with different positions on their container element, though this seems to be much more of an issue.

Comment: @Reuben seems to have an issue with the container's relative/absolute positioning. If I change top,left,right,bottom to ANY value it behaves goofy. Set to 0 and works as expected...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect its a stacking issue. Taking the elements out of the container by positioning them absolutely would solve the issue.